# Rails & ThinkingSphinx: Quorum matching as a percentage does not work?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sphinx, thinking-sphinx

I am trying to help make our search more acurate by using quorum matching with sphinx & thinking sphinx in our rails 3 app.

In a nutshell, using a % or float value does not work and generates the following error:

```
syntax error, unexpected TOK_KEYWORD, expecting TOK_INT near '0.5
```

Although the sphinx documents say this should work:

> Quorum matching operator introduces a kind of fuzzy matching. It will
>   only match those documents that pass a given threshold of given words.
>   The example above ("the world is a wonderful place"/3) will match all
>   documents that have at least 3 of the 6 specified words. Operator is
>   limited to 255 keywords. Instead of an absolute number, you can also
>   specify a number between 0.0 and 1.0 (standing for 0% and 100%), and
>   Sphinx will match only documents with at least the specified
>   percentage of given words. The same example above could also have been
>   written "the world is a wonderful place"/0.5 and it would match
>   documents with at least 50% of the 6 words.

However when I use a non-float value e.g. /2 it works or rather search executes without generating an error.

Can anyone see why this might be breaking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thinking Sphinx is passing this through to Sphinx itself, and it's Sphinx that's complaining. I just tested this locally, and it seems any float value for quorum matching fails. It may be worth raising this issue with the Sphinx team directly (on their forum or bug tracker).

Comment: qIt was only implemented in r3556, so requires something like sphinx 2.0.7 or above.

Comment: Wonder if it's a Sphinx 2.1 feature - it doesn't work on 2.0.8.